# finding values from several workbooks using the directory

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from several workbooks

the directory of the workbooks have order like this

```
c:\sheets\#number #month\worksheet #date
```

I would like to copy the same range in all workbooks

The month format is `MMM`

The date format us `DD-MMM-YYYY`

Comment: So you have no question, that's great :). If you actually have a question please see [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly so we could help you out where your get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                ' do your copy process here ...


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win010.htm

Comment: do i have to write the names of all files?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Try the code and see if it does what you need.  Post back if you have additional questions.